# SQL-How to Sum occurrences of a column value with specific case

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of information for runners

```
ID |  age | Miles| Date    | start_time |
-------------------------------------
901  | 25  |  9  | 1/1/2021|  8:00 AM
901  | 25  |  3  | 1/1/2021|  4:00 PM
901  | 25  |  10 | 1/2/2021|  10:00 AM
904  | 27  |  6  | 1/3/2021|  7:00 AM
905  | 45  |  4  | 1/4/2021|  10:00 AM
905  | 45  |  5  | 1/5/2021|  12:00 PM
```

I want to query for the count for all runners who have ran more than once and the sum of the miles ran. The condition is that if the runner have recorded runs more than once a day only the first run is considered, so dates will be the main factor for categorizing.

```
RunnersCount | Miles
--------------------
2            |  28
```

This results from id 901 who has ran on 1/1 and 1/2 and id 905 who ran 1/4 and 1/5 whos miles is 19 and 28 respectively.

What's the most efficient way of doing this? If one exists

Comment: 1) how do you define first run within a day if you only have the date of the run recorded? 2) what have you tried so far and where did you get stuck? 3) most efficient way from what point view?

Comment: Is the date really stored like that format in the tables? I second Shadow's comment about the definition of first and subsequent runs. How to know which one is first? Unless, if you store date+time or have another column that stores `start_time` or something like that or other methods you have like `id` etc., it's nearly impossible.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table yourtablename;`

Comment: @FaNo_FN no but I can add a new column for time started. how would the query be written then? I tried using cases but not sure if thats right

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Answer (score 1):

just another answer use FaNo_FN's data

```sql
with tab1 as(
select t1.*,
       row_number() over(partition by t1.id, t1.date order by t1.start_time) rn,
       count(*) over(partition by t1.id) cot
  from run_records t1
)
select count(distinct case when t1.cot > 1 then t1.id end),
       sum(case when t1.cot > 1 and t1.rn = 1 then t1.miles end)
  from tab1 t1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it were me, I would probably just store date+time with `datetime` datatype on `Date` column but separating them will do too. Maybe, at least with date and time are separated, the query can use indexes more efficiently. Your respond to my question about the date format in table was "no" so I assume that the date is stored with `DATE` datatype. Hence, your data table would probably look like this instead:

| ID | age | Miles | Date | start_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 901 | 25 | 9 | 2021-01-01 | 08:00:00 |
| 901 | 25 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 16:00:00 |
| 901 | 25 | 10 | 2021-01-02 | 10:00:00 |
| 904 | 27 | 6 | 2021-01-03 | 07:00:00 |
| 905 | 45 | 4 | 2021-01-04 | 10:00:00 |
| 905 | 45 | 5 | 2021-01-05 | 12:00:00 |

And assuming that your `start_time` is `TIME` datatype, the data would look like that (with 24hour time format). Then, maybe this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Total_runners, SUM(milesR) AS Total_Miles
  FROM
   (SELECT R.ID, SUM(Miles) milesR, COUNT(*) Total_runs
     FROM
     run_records R JOIN
          (SELECT ID, Date, MIN(start_time) AS minst FROM run_records
            GROUP BY ID, Date) minR
        ON R.ID=minR.ID AND R.Date=minR.Date AND R.start_time=minR.minst
     GROUP BY R.ID) TR
WHERE Total_runs > 1;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3b3c70f18c529b764010e32acdfaef2)